# XPath returning an empty [] search result in python

Tags: python, xpath

I was trying to extract the reviews from booking.com

```
URL = "https://www.booking.com/hotel/ph/oyo-518-mytown-amsterdam-manila.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaLQBiAEBmAEJuAEHyAEN2AED6AEBiAIBqAIDuALwtZuKBsACAdICJDZiZTlhNTRlLTc5MzktNGIwNC05NmZjLWI4Nzg3NGZhNWQ1MtgCBOACAQ;all_sr_blocks=601616502_275784337_2_0_0;checkin=2021-10-01;checkout=2021-10-02;dest_id=-2437894;dest_type=city;dist=0;group_adults=2;group_children=0;hapos=1;highlighted_blocks=601616502_275784337_2_0_0;hpos=1;no_rooms=1;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;sr_order=popularity;sr_pri_blocks=601616502_275784337_2_0_0__139646;srepoch=1632033539;srpvid=af482ec1c5c20263;type=total;ucfs=1&#tab-reviews"
```

and I'm using an XPATH which I copied verbatim from my browser.  These codes give me nothing.

```
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(URL.content)

tree.xpath('//*[@id="review_list_page_container"]/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/p/span[3]')
```

output: []

Any good heart who can assist please.  Thank you.

Comment: Please share the actual code - since you define `URL` as a string, it won't have `.content`. It's also not clear how you obtain your "output".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This website is loaded dynamically. Therefore you cannot extract data from this website with lxml.

You will need something like [Selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) to  extract data from such websites since it would be able to run the javascript that loads the actual content you are trying to scrape. Here is a [tutorial](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage) to get you started.